# I am using posix_memalign to allocate memory, but when I try to use the vector I get segmentation failure

Tags: c, memory, posix, allocation, memory-alignment

I created the following function that takes all the elements of the square matrix to a vector of the appropriate size.The function works correctly with malloc, but I need to create the vector with posix_memalign and there the error occurs.

```
void convert_matrix_to_vector(int **matrix, const int matrixSize, int **vector, int *vectorSize){

    int *vectorAux, i, j, k, vectorSizeAux;

    vectorSizeAux = matrixSize * matrixSize;
    posix_memalign((void **)&vectorAux, vectorSizeAux, vectorSizeAux * sizeof(int));    
    k = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < matrixSize; i++){
        for (j = 0; j < matrixSize; j++){
            vectorAux[k] = matrix[i][j];
            k++;
        }
    }
    free_matrix_memory(matrix, matrixSize);
    *vector = vectorAux;
    *vectorSize = k;
}
```

When I run the program, the value of vectorSizeAux is 16.

The error that appears is: Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.

When trying to execute the line:

```
vectorAux[k] = matrix[i][j];
```

Comment: When the crash happens and you catch it in a debugger, what are the values of `i`, `j` and `k`? Are they what you expect them to be?  Have you checked that `posix_memalign` succeeded? How do you call this `convert_matrix_to_vector` function? What is the value of `matrixSize`? Is `matrix` a valid pointer? Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve].

Comment: You do not check `posix_memalign` return value.

Comment: Many apologies for not putting the example as a minimal reproducible example. I ran the program again and apparently it fails with vectorSizeAux = 4. All other values are as expected.

Comment: What *are* the values of all involved variables when the crash happens? And you used a debugger to actually locate the crash at that specific line? And if you add a check for what `posix_memalign` returns, what does it return?

Comment: By the way, [the POSIX reference page](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/posix_memalign.html) states that the alignment must be a power of 2 ***and** also amultiple of `sizeof(void*)`*. If you're on a 64-bit system then `sizeof(void*)` will be `8` which makes `4` an invalid alignment.

Comment: Which is why you *always* check return values for errors...

Comment: By the way, what is the problem with using `malloc`? Why do you need to use `posix_memalign`? And have you checked the alignment of the memory returned by `malloc`?

Comment: Thank you very much, "Some programmer dude". The problem was that when working on a 64-bit system, the minimum size for vectorSizeAux must be 8, and that is why I got errors when running the program giving it values of 4, 8, 16 and 32. In the value of 4, posix_memalign failed and it no longer worked with the other values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is thanks to the user "Some programmer dude":

the POSIX reference page states that the alignment must be a power of 2 and also amultiple of sizeof(void*). If you're on a 64-bit system then sizeof(void*) will be 8 which makes 4 an invalid alignment.

That is why the minimum size for vectorSizeAux must be 8, and I got errors when running the program giving it values of 4, 8 and 16. In the value of 4, posix_memalign failed and the execution stopped and I no longer work with the other values.